# How to real time filter foreign key dropdown, based on previous foreign key dropdown selection in the model form?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 models, `Jobs` and `Çompany`. Both are taken as a foreign key to my current model `Tracker`. In the tracker CreateView form I am selecting the Company from the drropdown(Company model), also the Job Position(Job model).
The Job model also has a company field, which says for which company the job position is open. 
Now, what I want is, in my tracker form, as soon as I select a company from the dropdown, I want only the Job openings of that company to be listed in the Job foreign key dropdown. 
Let's say there are 3 job openings for Google, Engineer, Support and Developer. Currently my job position dropdown is displaying all the positons in the job model list. I want to filter them based on the company I select.

And the company also I'm chosing from the dropdown beside only, in the same form.

```
Is there a way, I can filter the dropdown real time?
```

Like having a dynamic foreign key dropdown which depends on my Company value chosen(dropdown again)?

```
class Tracker(models.Model):  
    company_applied = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position_applied = models.ForeignKey(Jobb, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Jobb(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
     return self.position_applied
```

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

       def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

How to achieve it? I searched a lot, I'm not able to find the exact words to search to get the solution. 
Also I'm new to Django..

Comment: Use `django-autocomplete-light` module

Comment: Okay, I shall read the documentation. Thanks!